# How to use a dojo widget inside a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dojo

Is there any way to re-use a component/widget from other library inside a react component?
E.g.

```
export default function App() {
 const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
 return (
  <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>{count}</button>
  <button id="btn" onClick={() => function(){
    require(["dijit/form/Button", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Button) {
      var button = new Button({
          label: "Click Me!",
          onClick: function(){ console.log("Opening a dojo dialog"); }
      }, "btn");
      button.startup();
  });
  }}>Open Dojo component</button>

  <br />
</div>
);
```

Here, this is a basic react component. I am trying to use a dojo button inside it but apparently does not work. I am actually thinking in the lines of having a button event in the react and call some javascript function which parses the dojo widget. Not sure if that will work.
Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your attempt didn't work is because you're still rendering plain buttons in the React JSX, and when you click that button you're creating a new Dojo button but you're not adding it to the DOM. Even if you did add it to the DOM, React might still remove it on a later re-render because it's not part of the JSX.

We've recently undergone an integration of React into an existing Dojo application, and the method we use to put Dojo widgets into React components is as follows.

The high level overview is that we create special React components that "host" Dojo widgets inside them. I'll start from the top and work my way down.

The usage of these hosted Dojo widgets is mostly straight forward, and looks something like the following JSX

```
<div>
  <Button
    dojoProps={{ label: "Add" }}
    dojoEvents={{ click: onAdd }}
  />
  <Button
    dojoProps={{ label: "Remove" }}
    dojoEvents={{ click: onRemove }}
  />
</div>
```

where `Button` is our Dojo hosting component. The entries in the `dojoProps` property are passed into the constructor of the widget and into `.set(...)` when the properties change. Then entries in `dojoEvents` are passed into `.on(...)` when being created and when they change as well.

The `Button` class looks like this (it's in TS, but should be easy to translate into JS)

```
import * as DojoButton from "dijit/form/Button";
import { DojoInReactComponent } from "../DojoInReactComponent";

export class Button extends DojoInReactComponent<DojoButton> {
  constructor(props: Button["props"]) {
    super(new DojoButton(props.dojoProps), props);
  }
}
```

We make one of these classes for each Dojo widget we wish to wrap and show in React and is re-usable throughout the project. Note that this is where the widget is created and the props are passed into the widget's constructor.

The important part of the implementation is in the `DojoInReactComponent` class:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as _WidgetBase from "dijit/_WidgetBase";

/**
 * A React component that hosts a Dojo widget
 */
export abstract class DojoInReactComponent
    <W extends _WidgetBase, P extends DojoInReactComponentProps<W> = DojoInReactComponentProps<W>>
    extends React.Component<P> {

    /** Stores a React Ref to the actual DOMNode that we place the widget at */
    private readonly widgetRef: React.RefObject<HTMLSpanElement>;
    /** Cache of the registered event handles for this widget (used to cleanup handles on unmount) */
    private readonly eventsRegistered: EventRegistrationCache<W> = {};
    /** The actual widget that will be stored in this component */
    readonly widget: W;

    constructor(widget: W, props: P) {
        super(props);
        this.widgetRef = React.createRef();
        this.widget = widget;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (!this.widgetRef.current) {
            throw new Error("this.widgetRef was not set");
        }

        // First, set properties
        this.widget.set(this.props.dojoProps ?? {});

        // Then set event handlers. This is the first time it happens so
        // the eventsRegistered cache is empty (ie: nothing to remove).
        this.addEventHandlers(this.props.dojoEvents);

        // Finally, place it at the domNode that this component created when it rendered.
        this.widget.placeAt(this.widgetRef.current);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps: P) {
        // First, update props. Note that we merge the old and new properties together here before setting to
        // ensure nothing drastically changes if we don't pass in a property. If we want it to change, we need to
        // explicitly pass it in to the dojoProps property in the TSX.
        // This also attempts to make it obvious that not setting a property in the TSX will leave it unchanged,
        // compared to it's existing value, as that's the default behaviour of Dojo widgets and .set().
        const props = { ...prevProps.dojoProps ?? {}, ...this.props.dojoProps ?? {} };
        this.widget.set(props);

        // Then update event handlers. Note that we don't do this in a "smart" way, but instead we just remove all
        // existing handlers, and then re-add the supplied ones. Generally it will mean removing and re-adding the same
        // handlers, but it's much easier than trying to diff them.
        this.removeAllEventHandlers();
        this.addEventHandlers(this.props.dojoEvents);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        // On cleanup we need to remove our handlers that we set up to ensure no memory leaks.
        this.removeAllEventHandlers();

        // Finally we destroy the widget
        this.widget.destroyRecursive();
    }

    private addEventHandlers(events: EventsType<W> | undefined) {
        if (!events) {
            return;
        }

        for (const key of keysOf(events)) {
            const newHandle = this.widget.on(key as any, events[key] as any);
            this.eventsRegistered[key] = newHandle;
        }
    }

    private removeAllEventHandlers() {
        for (const key of keysOf(this.eventsRegistered)) {
            const handle = this.eventsRegistered[key];
            if (handle) {
                handle.remove();
            }

            delete this.eventsRegistered[key];
        }
    }

    render() {
        return <span ref={this.widgetRef}></span>;
    }
}

function keysOf<T extends {}>(obj: T) {
    return Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof T>;
}

type EventsType<T extends _WidgetBase> = Record<string, () => void>;
type PropsType<T extends _WidgetBase> = Partial<T>;

export interface DojoInReactComponentProps<W extends _WidgetBase> {
    dojoProps?: PropsType<W>;
    dojoEvents?: EventsType<W>;
}

type EventRegistrationCache<W extends _WidgetBase> = Record<string, dojo.Handle>;
```

There's a bit to unpack here, but the general gist of it is:

- `render()` produces a simple `<span>` element that we keep a reference to to mount our Dojo widget to shortly
- `componentDidMount()` updates the properties and event handlers of the Dojo widget to our supplied properties. It then places the actual Dojo widget into the DOM produced by the React component
- `componentDidUpdate()` again updates the properties and event handlers if they changes due to a re-render of the React component
- `componentWillUnmount()` is called when the React component is being removed and does a teardown of the hosted Dojo widget by calling `.destroyRecursive()` to remove it from the DOM

The types down the bottom are just utility types to help TS infer everything for us, however `EventsType` and `EventsRegistrationCache` uses additional changes that are far too long to write out here, so I've replaced them with a stub (but if you're just using JS then it won't matter).

Let me know if you have any questions about it.